# Printing function addresses always prints 1 on linux

Tags: c++, printing, cout, virtual-memory

I'm developing a c++ program that is dealing with addresses for different variables and functions.

When I compiled my program on a Linux based OS, all functions including the main get the address of 1 instead of an 8 digit hexa number like other variables, which did not happen in Windows.

I wrote this small piece of code to explain the issue

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void Function1();
void Function1(){ 
}

int main(){
    int tmp;
    void (*a) ()=&Function1;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<<&Function1<<endl;
    cout<<&main<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

for all 3 cout calls, the output is 1 instead of the virtual address.

Comment: _"which did not happen in Windows"_ It should have done.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've just tried, didn't happen indeed, VS2013

Comment: @0d0a: Huh, same in VS2012. This is a bug in one or the other. http://stackoverflow.com/q/25540033/560648

Comment: please fix the indentation

Answer (score 7):

The pointer gets converted to another type, `bool`, because it is a function pointer and there are no overloads of `operator<<` in the `<iostream>` library for function pointers (because there are an infinite number of such types). The pointer points to some non-zero address because it has been initialized with the address of the function - so it gets converted to 1 (only 0x0 address would give you boolean 0).

### Solution

To assert correct behavior, you should cast the pointer to `void*` so you can use the [`operator<<` overload for `void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt):

```
ostream & operator <<( ostream &, const void * );
```

Example:

```
void Function1(){}

int main() {
    void ( *a) () = &Function1;
    cout << ( void*)( a) << endl;
    /* or better - being explicit about harshness of this design */
    cout << reinterpret_cast< void*> ( a) <, endl;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Fne4Mu

---

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 4.12 Boolean conversions [conv.bool]

> 1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true. A prvalue of type std::nullptr_t can be converted to a prvalue of type bool; the resulting value is false.

Comment: Note that in standard C++, it is illegal to cast a function pointer to a `void*` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645660/), but some compilers may allow it as an extension, but you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 3):

`<<` has no standard overload taking a function pointer; so instead, the pointer is converted to `bool` (since that's a legitimate implicit conversion), giving `1`, or `true` if you've used the `std::boolalpha` manipulator on the stream.

If you want the address, you'll have to explicitly convert it to an object pointer:

```
std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&Function1) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Note that in standard C++, it is illegal to cast a function pointer to a `void*` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36645660/), but some compilers may allow it as an extension, but you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 0):

If I change your code to the following, the function pointer addresses will be displayed correctly:

```
void Function1() {
}

int main() {
    void*a = (void*)&Function1;
    cout<<a<<endl;
    cout<< (void*)&Function1<<endl;
    cout<< (void*)&main<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x8048710
0x8048710
0x8048570
```

See the [working sample here](http://ideone.com/ADREqt) please.

---

The problem is, there's a standard operator overload available for

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,void*)
```

but not for function pointers

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,void (Function1Type*)())
```

and the least valid conversion draws

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&,bool)
```

where everything other than `0x00000000` is `true`.

Comment: @AbdulazizAldyaf If you want to _thank_ me or the community you might consider [accepting this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer): Just click that big white checkmark, just left beneath my post (you'll even earn rep for doing this).