# Why std::cout << main << std::endl prints 1?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << main << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why it prints 1 in command line ?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you *expecting* this code to print? main in this case is a function pointer.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Is it? Remember `main` is special...

Comment: It is probably undefined behaviour. Thou shalt not name main. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128321/can-main-function-call-itself-in-c/2128727#2128727.

Comment: You are not allowed to use `main` in your program. [Most sane compilers will warn you.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5512d094bedd615) It will still print `1` for the name of a normal function, because the function pointer gets implicitly converted to `bool`.

Comment: `main` shall not be _used_ within a program. _used_ i.e. _"the name appears in a potentially-evaluated expression."_

Comment: @T.C.: You mean, "The function main shall not be used within a program." which makes it ill-formed. Still, after issuing a diagnostic the compiler is free to accept it with whatever semantics it wants anyway.

Comment: related: function pointers will be cast into bool http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540033/is-visual-studio-buggy-in-printing-the-function-address

Answer (score 6):

Your program is ill-formed. N4140:

> §3.6.1/3 The function `main` shall not be used within a program. [...]

If we pretend that the program wasn't ill-formed, the most likely explanation is the standard conversions:

> §4.3/1 An lvalue of function type `T` can be converted to a prvalue of
>   type "pointer to `T`." The result is a pointer to the function.
>
> §4.12/1 A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or
>   pointer to member type can be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`. A
>   zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is
>   converted to `false`; any other value is converted to `true`. For
>   direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can be
>   converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

If you insist on doing this, try:

```
std::cout << (void*)main << std::endl;
```

Comment: Don't forget the part where `std::ostream` does not have a `<<` operator that accepts a function pointer with signature `int (*)(void)`, which is why the pointer is being converted to another type at all.

Comment: in [this quuestion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2741896/995714) I saw `main` was used many times

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc That's C. I haven't seen any standard quotations so far that say it's ill-formed in C.